# Would like to use ZEBRA EMDK on Mobile phones (samsung S6) for barcode scanning purpose thru Camera as a scanner

Tags: android

1.I have added below line on manifest file

```
<uses-library android:name="com.symbol.emdk" android:required="false" />
```

2.I have added below dependency as per my directory path

```
dependencies {
provided fileTree(include: ['com.symbol.emdk.jar'], dir: 'C:\\Users\\<YOUR USER NAME>\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\add-ons\\addon-symbol-emdk_v4.2_API-19\\libs')
compile fileTree(exclude: ['com.symbol.emdk.jar'], dir: 'libs')}
```

3. I have added class "BarcodeScanEngine" as per the below Repo (https://gist.github.com/esquijarosa/1c79059c8833f922af945fa0719fad80)
4. Now, the problem is when i'm creating object for BarcodeScanEngine on MainActivity class it is giving the runtime error as

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sample.zebrascanengine.BarcodeScannerEngine ...

So, my question is am i doing something fundamentally wrong as in i shouldn't be using EDMK for mobile phones ? or am i missing something to get rid of the error ?

Answer (score 2):

Zebra's EMDK can only be used on Zebra devices.
It is possible to have an application that uses the EMDK running on a consumer device, like your Samsung S6, but only if you avoid to do any call to the EMDK library.

The idea is that your MainActivity needs to check if the EMDK library is available on the device and only at that point you instantiate the BarcodeScanEngine class.

You can find more information about this in [Zebra's EMDK reference guide](http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/6-3/guide/programming_practices/#creatingacommonapplicationtorunonzebraandnonzebradevices).

*Disaclaimer: I work for Zebra Technologies.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, When i try to do "Device Runtime Deployment" for EMDK on Samsung S6, im getting "Error: The EMDK update is not supported on this device."

Comment: Well that's is exactly the point, the EMDK is only supports Zebra's devices.

Comment: You can evaluate [this sample application](https://github.com/darryncampbell/GenericScanWedge) that implement a sample solution to handle barcode scanning on consumer and Zebra devices.